# How to support different screensizes (different phones) with android

Tags: android, android-layout

For a school project I have to create an app, but now I have a question. I made a layout and changed the screensize to see if the layout was still the same, but it wasn't unfortunately. I hope someone can help me with this. Here are some screenshots:

The first picture is 5.5 inch and the second picture is 5 inch
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: @codeMagic so I should do that for all different screensizes like 4,7 inch, 5 inch, 5.2 inch, 5.5 inch, 5.7 inch etc?

Comment: You do it for whatever screen differences you care to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this view I think that the better way to make the view resize, depending the device screen, is working with *LinearLayout* and *weight_sum*, giving a *layout_weight* value to each child depending the size of each.

[Here a good tutorial.](https://youtu.be/c7TsE7D0v10)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate difference mobile phone using its screen size, android os etc...

Folder name like: 
res/layout-hdpi -for high density device
res/layout-xdpi -for high density device
res/layout-xxdpi -for high density device

or

res/layout-w320dp-h640dp

or

res/layout-sw600dp -for tablet 7inch